Объединить Строки и кортеж

Напишите программу, которая объединяет кортеж и строку.

Мой ответ. Сомневаюсь, что правильно сделал:
a=input("Введите слово")
b=input(tuple("Введите фразу"))
c= a + b
print (c)


Валидный код, объединяющий кортеж и строку: (); ''.

Мда, ваше задание непонятное.

@StanislavVolodarskiy А где в вашем примере кортеж? )

Ваш код выдаст ошибку, tuple надо ставить перед input, а сейчас код пытается сделать кортежем "Введите фразу", а не результат ввода

@CrazyElf, @>>> type(()) -> <class 'tuple'>.

Реализовать подобное можно вот таким образом.
my_tuple = tuple(input('Введите: ')) # Запрашиваем данные
my_string = input('Введите строку: ')

result = ''.join(map(str, my_tuple)) + my_string # Создаём переменную result, в которую записываем наши значения
print(result) # Выводим переменную


Если честно, сам не понимаю, что должно тут получиться. Задание странное

Перечитал ваше задание, моё решение полностью соответствует его критериям. Можете убедиться в этом сами.

У вас ошибку выдает: 'tuple' object is not callable

Какую версию python используете, редактировали ли вы что-то в коде? Проверил на 3.8 и 3.11 всё стабильно работает.

Возможно вы забываете разделить 2 кортежа запятой.

Я в Google Collab пишу код

В коде ничего не редактировал

https://i.imgur.com/F4A2YzX.jpeg

Не совсем понимаю, как разделить кортежи. Запятые ставил в разных местах, ошибку все-равно выдает. Поставил запятую в первой строке, выдало ошибку
my_tuple = tuple(input('Введите: ')),
my_string = str(input('Введите строку: '))
result = ''.join(map(str, my_tuple)) + my_string # Создаём переменную result, в которую записываем наши значения
print(result) # Выводим переменную

input - это уже строка, её не нужно дополнительно преобразовывать через str
